# This explanation of Geologic Time Scale as a calendar year

Tags: discourse-context

This is from [a webpage](https://www.nps.gov/subjects/geology/geotime.htm#collapseCollapsible1596219611065).

> Geologic time began ticking when Earth formed ~4.6 billion years ago.
> Scaling this large amount of time to our calendar year, each of the 12
> months of the geologic calendar year represents 383 million years (4.6
> billion / 12). Generally speaking, each year has 365 days, so each day
> represents 12.6 million years (4.6 billion / 365) on our geologic
> calendar. Each day has 24 hours, so one hour represents 525,114
> “geologic years” (4.6 billion / [365 × 24]). Each hour has 60 minutes,
> so one minute represents 8,752 “geologic years” (4.6 billion / [365 ×
> 24 × 60]). Finally, each minute has 60 seconds, so each “geologic
> second” represents 146 years (4.6 billion / [365 × 24 × 60 × 60]).

I think this explanation of Geologic Time Scale as a calendar year is a little confusing.

So I rephrased it like this:

> Geologic time began ticking when Earth formed ~4.6 billion years ago.
> Scaling this large amount of time to our calendar year, each of the 12
> months of the geologic calendar year represents 383 million years (4.6
> billion / 12). Generally speaking, each year has 365 days, so each day
> represents 12.6 million years (4.6 billion / 365) on our geologic
> calendar. Each day has 24 hours, so one **geologic** hour represents
> 525,114 **years** (4.6 billion / [365 × 24]). Each hour has 60
> minutes, so one **geologic** minute represents 8,752 **years** (4.6
> billion / [365 × 24 × 60]). Finally, each minute has 60 seconds, so
> each “geologic second” represents 146 years (4.6 billion / [365 × 24 ×
> 60 × 60]).

I wonder whether I understand the Time Scale right and rephrased the explanation appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have understood it correctly, yes. The authors have clearly made a mistake: if they're using "geologic" as intended when they write "the geologic calendar year" and "each 'geologic second'", then they're using it the opposite of how it's intended when they write "525,114 'geologic years'" and "8,752 'geologic years'". Your changes fix this mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much.